# How to remove this gap from the Android layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, drawerlayout

I tried everything that I could to remove this gap (`shown in the screenshot below`) from the bottom of the layout, however got nothing but disappointment!

**Here is the xml code of `tournament_home.xml`:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_tournament_home"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_tournament_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_tournament_home">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lnl_home_screen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/frame_home_screen_tournament_name"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ab9.com.cricliveptc.tabs.SlidingTabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:elevation="2dp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_shadow"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/margin2x"
                android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is the screenshot, where you can clearly *see a small horizontal gap left at the bottom of the screen.*

[image: Screenshot of the gap appearing at the bottom of the screen layout]

How to fix that?

Comment: Have you checked the margins and padding settings of the parent Relative Layout?

Comment: @Abhi yes, I did. I haven't applied any margin and/or padding to the parent layout.

Comment: try removing negative padding of view pager

Comment: @VivekMishra, tried. It moves layout slightly down but not entirely. Besides, I have applied `android:layout_height="0dp" and android:layout_weight="1"` to the ViewPager, which makes (should make) it occupy entire screen irrespective of that negative padding.

Comment: Remove `android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"` (at a guess).

Comment: @Tigger, check my previous comment.

Comment: This gap I think comes everywhere and it's only with the selection. I also found this gap in every layout that I have created

Comment: @VivekMishra - that's because your design is wrong, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the `android:layout_weight="1"` of `viewpager` and replace `android:layout_height="0dp"` with `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html

> `DrawerLayout` ***acts as a top-level*** container for window content that
>   allows for interactive "drawer" views to be pulled out from the edge
>   of the window.

You should not use that `RelativeLayout` as the top-level.that could be something like this with adding `Toolbar` in your contents:

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_tournament_home">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnl_home_screen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/frame_home_screen_tournament_name"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarmain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        <ab9.com.cricliveptc.tabs.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:elevation="2dp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_shadow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/margin2x"
            android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <!-- this is not a good place -->
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Also, i'd rather to use `CoordinatorLayout` nowadays with `SupportLibrary`.

One more thing, your design is completly wrong i guess, `RecyclerView` is going to be like `NavigationDrawer` and that's not what android docs says.

You may want to take a look at here also: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: your answer is only related with drawer layout. I said that whenever I select any root layout in graphical editor it shows slight gap at the end

Comment: Have you tried this?: android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Answer (score 0):

**Remove `android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"` from your layout.**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_tournament_home"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_tournament_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_tournament_home">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lnl_home_screen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/frame_home_screen_tournament_name"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ab9.com.cricliveptc.tabs.SlidingTabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:elevation="2dp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_shadow"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/margin2x"
                android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"` as others have stated. I'm guessing that you mean `android:layout_marginTop="4dp"` anyways.

If you want a margin between the `View` and the `ViewPager` just set a bottom margin to the `View` element.

The reason is that `android:layout_height="0dp" and android:layout_weight="1"` is working but then you are setting a negative top margin which is moving up the element.